# Time period diagram (bar chart) - what is its more precise/widely used name?

Tags: data-visualization, terminology, barplot, javascript

I want to make a diagram like this to display the career spans of several soccer players one below the next:

[image: Career span diagram]

I know it's basically a bar chart, but I was hoping this has a more specific name, because I want to search the web to find out whether d3.js can easily render one that is suitable for this specific kind of usage.

Comment: Terms like "real name" presuppose more about terminology than is justified. No committee or supervising genius lays down the law ineluctably on correct names. But "time line" is a common name. https://www.papress.com/html/book.details.page.tpl?isbn=9781568987637 shows that its pedigree is centuries long.

Comment: Fair enough, and thanks for the answer. I didn't want to crowd the title by saying "most widely accepted and precise name" to make it less readable.

Comment: In many respects this is like a [Gantt chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart), though that is usually used in a project management setting

Comment: @NickCox, you should probably make that an 'official' answer. I don't know if something else will come up, & otherwise this will go officially unanswered.

Comment: I have removed from the question the fact that this was [originally posted on Mathematics SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1926017/time-period-diagram-bar-chart-what-is-its-real-name) but closed there as off-topic - I appreciate your honesty over that fact, but I don't think it makes sense to make that the first sentence of the question - as that's the bit that shows up in search previews, it helps if the first sentence quickly gets to the point of the question!

Comment: @gung Thanks for the suggestion. I will see if I can add to my minimal answer in due course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terms like "real name" presuppose more about terminology than is justified. No committee or supervising genius lays down the law ineluctably on correct names.

But "time line" is a common name. The splendid scholarly survey by Rosenberg and Grafton [(see reference here)](http://papress.com/html/book.details.page.tpl?isbn=9781568987637) shows that its pedigree is centuries long (and, for what it's worth, antedates William Playfair on the bar chart strict sense).